# Package loading overhead

Tags: plsql

I have package with around 30 proc/functions. This gets invoked from servel places. At one place it's using only 2 functions out of 30. When packages gets invoked it will load all proc/functions in the memory. However, in this case it's a overhead. Is there any way to avoid this?

*Note :- I can not create these two proc/functions again.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question here. A package is loaded into memory as a single unit. If you can't separate the functions/procedures from that package into another to save on "overhead" then you've eliminated all options.

What is the concern? Memory overhead? Quoting from [Don Burleson](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_proc.htm), who is not my favorite source but was handy, packages are loaded into shared pool memory ONCE unless paged out. What may be viewed as overhead is not per *session*, it is per *instance*.

Comment: Agreed. Although there is overhead it is minimal. When designing a new system the overhead of loading a package in the shared pool should be the least of your concerns in your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The only real overhead to be at all concerned about is the usage of the session's PGA allocation by variables declared globally in the package.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call a procedure from your package, the whole package will be loaded to the database memory space. You should not create a package for holding general procedures just to organize your code. Procedures and functions are combined as a package if they are correlated. If the aren't, you should create new package for each one.